# Remove padding between footer img & footer background

Tags: html, css

Have some really simple question but i can't find an answer for it

So basically i have a footer logo and then goes background below it.
I have a small padding (white space?) between img and div, how to remove it?

HTML:

```
    <img src="footer_header.png"/>
    <div class="footeris">text</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footeris {
    background:#272727;
}
```

Comment: Please add more details, like a Screenshot of what you tried or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Hard to say without more information, but it sounds like applying `display: block` to the image should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add display:block to image. Image are by default inline, hence the white space.

```css
.footeris {
    background:#272727;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

img{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
    <div class="footeris">text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just include display:block in your img css ,you are getting white space because img is inline element by default make it block

please read the article for more information 
http://mor10.com/removing-white-space-image-elements-inline-elements-descenders/

```css
.footeris {
  background: #272727;
}
img {
  display: block;width:30%;
 
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
<div class="footeris">text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<img id="img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<div id="footeris">text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footeris {
    background:#272727;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

img{
    display:block;
     margin:0;  
}
```